# Android SDK Change text when Button clicked

Tags: android, button, sdk

```
 package com.purelymean.earnings;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Main extends Activity{
     /**Called when activity is first created. */
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     }
 }
```

What do I need to put so that when the button is clicked it will change the `textview` to whatever i put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an `OnClickListener` to your button and override `onClick` function to set your desire text in your `TextView`

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       tx.setText("yourtext");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `OnClickListener` to your button and thats all you need.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       tx.setText("It Works!");
   }
});
```